# Drupal : how to get file size of an image in views

Tags: drupal

I'm build an image gallery and want to display the filesize of an image along with the image thumbnail in a view. Can't figure out how to access this information and display it.

Looked around for a module but can't find any. I am turning around.

Glad if someone could give me a clue to start with.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add a relationship in the views UI to the files table. That'll give you access to the file size, mime type, etc.

Comment: Keep in mind that these numbers are only accurate if you totally manage your files through Drupal.  If you manually replace files (eg, to get around POST filesize limits), then this table isn't 100% accurate.

Comment: Very elegant solution; also learned something. Thank you very much.

Comment: :-) My pleasure. Views is remarkably powerful, relationships will serve you well.

Comment: By adding the file table in relationship, you will have duplicate content